# How to resize file inserted into word document (autoresize)

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in, enterprise-architect

I write (c#, .net framework 4.0) Add-in for Enterprise Architect and I have problem with formating file inserting to Word document.
This file I'm reading from Element.LinkedDocument (Repository.GetElementByID(kl.ElementID).GetLinkedDocument()), inserting to doc (Range.InsertFile()) and it is working.
But sometimes size (vertical or horizontal) of file in doc is to big, and I have to resize it to maximum in page document (autoresize, if its possible). Do you have any ideas how can I expand my code?

```
String linkedDocument = Repository.GetElementByID(kl.ElementID).GetLinkedDocument();
if (linkedDocument.Length > 0)
{
  String tmpFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() + ".rtf";
  using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(tmpFileName))
    outfile.Write(linkedDocument);

  dokMD.Paragraphs.Add();
  par = dokMD.Paragraphs.Last;
  par.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers(WdNumberType.wdNumberAllNumbers);
  par.set_Style("Normal");
  object brak = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
  par.Range.InsertFile(tmpFileName, brak, false);
  //... autosize
  File.Delete(tmpFileName);
  System.IO.File.Delete(tmpFileName);
}
```

Comment: Needs some clarification. What is dokMD?

Comment: Word._Document dokMD

Comment: This problem is resolved in another way. I generate RTF document with class generator, and this is easier because resolved problem with formatting included RTF document into main document. It is necessary to control (and setting) orientation sections in main document. I describe it in another forum:
http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1412973014